# npm install react-native-webrtc failed

Tags: node.js, react-native, react-native-webrtc

npm install react-native-webrtc --save

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node tools/downloadWebRTC.js
npm ERR! Downloading https://github.com/jitsi/webrtc/releases/download/v106.0.1/android-webrtc.zip...
npm ERR! node:internal/process/promises:246
npm ERR!           triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
npm ERR!           ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR!     at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:220:20) {
npm ERR!   errno: -4077,
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNRESET',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'read'
npm ERR! }
```

jdk:1.8；
node:16.12.0；
how can i fix it up?

Comment: This is a network issue that indicates that the other end hung up. GitHub did have a brief incident a few hours ago, possibly related. It looks like it's working now (on my machine), so if you try again and it's still failing, and if your connection is stable, I would open an issue on the repo or wait a few hours. Edit: oh, I see you've already opened an issue.

Comment: You could also set `RN_WEBRTC_SKIP_DOWNLOAD=1` before running `npm i`, download the package manually, unzip it, and place it in `android/libs` in that node_module's directory (see [this file](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc/blob/master/tools/downloadWebRTC.js)).

Answer (score 0):

Try this command.

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

if not run this

```
npm config get proxy
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the error posted in the question.